# Creating a graph to show values for different groups

Tags: r, plot

HI sorry if this has been asked before I am trying to plot the following data called Users.age:
[image: Dataset]

I want the age groups to be plotted by the point being a different colour to show the different groupings, the x axis would be each of the years and the y axis would be the frequency.
The problem I am having is I am not sure where to start as the y value is all within the data.

Comment: You'll first need to reshape your data from wide to long. See: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html Also please do not take screenshots of your data. Instead use `dput()` and paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example how you could apply tidyr::pivot_longer and ggplot to create the desired graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(age= c("16-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54"), 
                   "y2014" = c(100,200,300,400),
                   "y2015" = c(250,350,450,550),
                   "y2016" = c(240, 340,440,550))

dataLong <- tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols=c("y2014", "y2015", "y2016"))
dataLong$year <- as.numeric(sub(".", "", dataLong$name))

ggplot(dataLong) +
  geom_point(aes(x=year, y=value, col=age))
  # + geom_line(aes(x=year, y=value, col=age)) if you would like to have lines instead of points
```

Comment: i did it and it looks really pretty :)
I just need to figure out how to add all my many linear regression lines to the graph now

Comment: you can use somehting like: 
`+geom_smooth(aes(x=year, y=value, group=age, col=age), method=lm, se=FALSE)`